# Why getting Uid not working, from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Java:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                userName = Objects.requireNonNull(user).getDisplayName();
                profileNameEdit.setText(userName);
                userEmail = user.getEmail();
                profileEmailEdit.setText(userEmail);
                String userID = user.getUid();
```

All is OK besides `user.getUid()`. This request simply returns nothing (not null, simple empty).

**How to get a user ID?**

Comment: Can you Log `user` and let me know if you got the correct info please

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Tried it @Артем Ильинский ?

Comment: I added my comment yesterday, see it.

Comment: Then you should mark any answer as a correct if it's solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... String userID was empty before putting text from it to TextView. Close answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   if (user != null) {
         // User is signed in
         userName = user.getDisplayName();
         profileNameEdit.setText(userName);
         userEmail = user.getEmail();
         profileEmailEdit.setText(userEmail);
         String mUid = user.getUid();
         //Set text here not only get the Uid                                                
}
else {
         Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "No user logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

If it doesn't work try to get the `Uid` doing this :

```
String mUid=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                          .child(user.getUid());
```

or

```
String mUid=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                              .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()getCurrentUser().getUid());
```